# How to structure Meteor app and load into Meteor shell

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm having a number of issues putting together a very simple piece of code as I learn Meteor. See the comments, which are questions.

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import { Post } from './schema'
// Why is this required to make Post available in Meteor.startup?
// Isn't there auto-loading?

Meteor.startup(() => {
    console.log(Post)
    // This works, but why isn't Post available to meteor shell?
});
```

**server/schema.js**

```
import { Post } from './models/post'
export { Post }
```

**server/models/post.js**

```
import { Class } from 'meteor/jagi:astronomy';
// Why can't this be imported elsewhere, like main.js?

const Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
const Post = Class.create({
  name: 'Post',
  collection: Posts,
  fields: {
    title: { type: String },
    userId: String,
    publishedAt: Date
  },
});

export { Post }
```

In addition to these questions, how can I load my app into meteor shell? `Post` is undefined there, even though it's defined in `Meteor.startup`. I tried using `.load` with an absolute path, but this breaks my app's imports, which use relative paths.

As for which errors I'm confused about:

- When I try and use `import` inside `Meteor.startup()`, I get an error that the keyword `import` is undefined. I'm using the `ecmascript` package.
- When I don't `import { Class }` in the same file where I use `Class`, I get an unknown keyword error.
- If I don't `import { Post }` in main.js, then `Post` is undefined.
- Not able to load app into Meteor shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access exported objects in Meteor shell, use `require`:

```
> require('server/schema.js').Posts.findOne();
```

To access objects exported by packages, use the package name:

```
> require('react').PropTypes;
```

The reason you can't access an object that's imported by another js file is that each file has its own scope here. When Meteor builds your app, it doesn't just concatenate js files like many other build systems do, and that's *really* a good thing.

Basically a Javascript object gets created for every js file you write. Anything you export in a js file becomes a field in this object which you can access by using `require`. And `import` is just a nicer version of the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Unless I want to pass my dependencies as arguments to functions, should I include the same dependencies in multiple files? Is there not a way to share scope from "includer" to "included"?

Comment: Yes, each js file should import all their dependencies independently. By default you can't inherit dependencies. (Well, I'm sure there are many ways to hack around this, since it's Javascript.)

Comment: Is there still autoloading?

Comment: Yes. In fact, Meteor's production build creates a single monolithic js file for you app that contains every source file and package.

Comment: Okay, but why do I have to `import { Post } from './schema'` in my main.js file then?

Comment: Because `Post` is not a toplevel object, although it looks like one. It's defined inside the `schema.js` file scope, which is not visible from the scope of `main.js`.

Comment: Awesome - got it working. Know of a way to auto-import stuff into meteor shell?